# Clustering for medium data

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

Which clustering method is good in R for a data with ~32,000 subjectsa and 10 variables, hierarchical or k-means?

Comment: Did you try to search the site? What did you find?

Comment: "Good" in what sense? The data is not that big, so I guess this is not a computational issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequently faced issues while clustering are, 
**1. full distance matrix,
2. Memory,
3. runtime.**

In hierarchical clustering, we create hierarchical decomposition of the given set of data in two ways such as from bottom to the top or top to down. On the basis how we create hierarchical decomposition we divide this method into two approaches one is agglomerative approach and other is the divisive approach. Hence, hierarchical clustering is the iterative process. Hierarchical clustering builds clusters within clusters and does not require a pre-specified number of clusters like k means. If you run hclust from R for a bigger dataset, it will demand higher RAM.

In k-means clustering, we try to identify the best way to divide the data into k sets simultaneously. A good approach is to take k items from the data set as initial cluster representatives, assign all items to the cluster whose representative is closest, and then calculate the cluster mean as a new representative; until it converges (all clusters stay the same).

Apart from that following are the pros and cons of each of techniques:

- **KMEANS**

**Advantages**

• Easy  to  implement
• With  a   large   number  of  variables,  K-Means may be  computationally faster  than hierarchical   clustering  (if K   is  small). 
• k-Means   may produce tigher  clusters    than    hierarchical    clustering
• An    instance    can change  cluster (move   to  another cluster)    when    the centroids   are recomputed.

**Disadvantages**

• Difficult to  predict the number  of  clusters    (K-Value)
• Initial   seeds   have    a   strong  impact  on  the final   results 
• The   order   of  the data    has an  impact  on  the final   results 
• Sensitive to  scale:  rescaling   your    datasets    (normalization  or  standardizaHon) will    completely  change  results.    While   this    itself  is  not bad,    not realizing   that    you have    to  spend   extra   attention on    to  scaling your    data    might   be  bad.

- **Hierarchical**

**Advantages**

• Hierarchical  clustering  outputs a   hierarchy,  ie  a   structure   that    is  more    informative than    the unstructured    set of  flat    clusters    returned    by  k-means.    Therefore,  it  is  easier  to  decide  on  the number  of  clusters    by  looking at  the dendrogram
• Easy  to  implement

**Disadvantages**

• It    is  not possible    to  undo    the previous    step:   once    the instances   have    been    assigned    to  a   cluster,    they    can no  longer  be  moved   around.
• Time  complexity: not suitable    for large   datasets
• Initial seeds have    a   strong  impact  on  the final   results 
• The   order   of  the data    has an  impact  on  the final   results 
• Very  sensitive   to  outliers

From all consideration, in my opinion KMeans should be preferred choice.

Comment: Welcome to CV and thank you for your great answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that @Tabbi. Please mark accept for my answer. :)